# jQuery validate.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use this great jQuery script but I receive an error with debug mode "----This is a debug mode, you got a problem with your form, it will try to help you, refresh when you think you nailed down the problem you are not going into the success function and `jsonValidateReturn` return nothing-----" or display this inside Firefox errors console:

> Error: `data.jsonValidateReturn` is undefined Source file:
> js/jquery.validationEngine.js

When I check an available username all is ok and it validates correctly all fields...
ajaxsubmitregister.php controls all

```
require_once("../config/config.php");
$arrayToJs = array();
$arrayToJs[0] = $validateId;
$arrayToJs[1] = $validateError;
$isValidate = true;  

if($isValidate == true)
{
    echo "true";
}
else
{ 
    $isValidate = false;

    if (!function_exists('json_encode'))
    {
        function json_encode($a=false)
        {
            if (is_null($a)) return 'null';
            if ($a === false) return 'false';
            if ($a === true) return 'true';
            if (is_scalar($a))
            {
            if (is_float($a))
            {
                // Always use "." for floats.
                return floatval(str_replace(",", ".", strval($a)));
            }

            if (is_string($a))
            {
                static $jsonReplaces = array(array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"'), array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"'));
                return '"' . str_replace($jsonReplaces[0], $jsonReplaces[1], $a) . '"';
            }
            else
                return $a;
        }

        $isList = true;

        for ($i = 0, reset($a); $i < count($a); $i++, next($a))
        {
            if (key($a) !== $i)
            {
                $isList = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        $result = array();

        if ($isList)
        {
            foreach ($a as $v) $result[] = json_encode($v);
            return '[' . join(',', $result) . ']';
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($a as $k => $v) $result[] = json_encode($k).':'.json_encode($v);
            return '{' . join(',', $result) . '}';
        }
    }
}

echo'{"jsonValidateReturn":'.json_encode($arrayToJs).'}';
}
```

Comment: @Reigel was wondering the same thing?

Comment: Probably  I was wrong to check this option